# Jax-WS: message validation

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I communicate with a SOAP-service that throws that exception because of my message.

```
com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.SOAPTextImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement
```

I think it is Java JAX-WS and the problem is somewhere in the XML of the SOAP.

Now I think of building also a simple service that gives me the chance to parse my own message.

Is there a fast an simple way with JAX-WS to parse a string that represents a SOAP-message?
Or do I need to build it full up (WSDL, ...).

Or is there maybe a SOAP-validator that uses JAX-WS?

I just have the problem with this one service. I communiacate with a bunch of others that are fine with my message. So I think it is specific to Java and  implementation.

Thanks for help.
Chris

Comment: Are you certain the exception’s stack trace doesn’t indicate that the cast is taking place in your own code?

Comment: Thats all I get. It is not my service.

Comment: Can you provide the entire stack trace of the exception?